# React Native maps dynamic location leads to React state update on unmounted component

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I have a `Mapview` component and a `Marker` component inside it as below:

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import MapView, {PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Marker} from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';
import Toast from 'react-native-root-toast';

import {ThemeContext} from '~/utils/theme-context';
import {MAP_STYLE} from '~/utils/map.style';
import {Colors} from '~/styles';

const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.01;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.01;

const Map = props => {
  const themeContext = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const mapStyle = MAP_STYLE;
  let map = null;
  let initialRegion = {
    latitude: 35.78825,
    longitude: -120.4324,
    latitudeDelta: 0.015,
    longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
  };
  const [region, setRegion] = useState(initialRegion);

  const getCurrentPosition = Geolocation.getCurrentPosition;
  const mapAnimation = map?.current.animateToRegion;

  useEffect(() => {
    const animate = location => {
      if (map) {
        mapAnimation(location, 1000);
      }
    };
    const getPositionHandler = () => {
      return getCurrentPosition(
        info => {
          const location = {
            latitude: info.coords.latitude,
            longitude: info.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          };

          animate(location);
          setRegion(location);
        },
        error => {
          Toast.show(error.message, {
            backgroundColor: Colors.ERROR,
            textColor: Colors.WHITE,
          });
        },
      );
    };
    getPositionHandler();
  }, [getCurrentPosition, mapAnimation, map]);

  return (
    <MapView
      ref={map}
      provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
      style={styles.map}
      customMapStyle={themeContext.theme === 'light' ? [] : mapStyle}
      region={region}>
      <Marker
        coordinate={{latitude: region.latitude, longitude: region.longitude}}
      />
    </MapView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    borderRadius: 24,
  },
});

export default Map;
```

I seem to be stuck into this problem, even though it doesn't obstruct me from coding further, but the error speaks about memory leaks etc. which brings forth some concern on my side.

Comment: Does the map animate properly?

Comment: no, it is going to the region based on the state being updated

Answer (score 0):

I think your `map` ref might be the problem here. It get's initialized on every render and set to the ref of a newly rendered map. Although, if the map animates properly, then I wouldn't be sure.

Try using `useRef` instead and see if the warning goes away.

`const map = useRef(null)`

`const mapAnimation = map.current?.animateToRegion;`

Comment: i am getting an error, while using useRef, TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'map.current.animateToRegion')